# How to start tracking an old BugSense enabled Android app?

Tags: splunk, bugsense

I’m testing an old Android app that uses BugSense, it works great but I'm getting some warnings in the log like this

```
W/BugSenseHandler: Transmitting ping Exception Unable to resolve host "ticks2.bugsense.com": No address associated with hostname
```

What I did was just to change the code like follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, my_new_mint_api_key);
}
```

...but I’m still seeing the error, can I just replace the old BugSense API key with a new Splunk MINT key like in the code above to start tracking the application again?

Comment: I don't know much about the bugsense -> MINT transition, but that is an odd exception since ticks2.bugsense.com does indeed have an address in public DNS (running a dig command like below). Is your internet connectivity from the device / service working? Is the app allowed to talk to the internet? 

     `$ dig +short @8.8.8.8 ticks2.bugsense.com` -> 
     `52.8.132.234`

Comment: @Charlie Yes, Google Analytics is enabled too and I see the data ok from the Analytics' report.